# C++ template to check if input type implements `operator []`

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to use template to check if input type implements `operator[]`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct has_bracket
{
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct has_bracket<T, decltype(T::operator[])>
{
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};
```

But it didn't work. It always output 0 no matter which type I input.

```
struct Test 
{
    int operator[](size_t n) { return 0; }
};

struct CTest
{
    int operator[](size_t n) const { return 0; }
};


int main()
{
    cout << has_bracket<int>::value << endl;             // output: 0
    cout << has_bracket<double>::value << endl;          // output: 0
    cout << has_bracket<Test>::value << endl;            // output: 0
    cout << has_bracket<CTest>::value << endl;           // output: 0
    cout << has_bracket<vector<int>>::value << endl;     // output: 0

    return 0;
}
```

I think that if `T = int` or `T = double`, `decltype(&T::operator[])` will fail and the primary `has_bracket` will be used according to SFINAE. If `T = Test` or `T = CTest` or `T = vector<int>`, the specialization one will be instantiated, leads to the `has_bracket<T>::value` be 1.
Is there something wrong? How to fix this problem to let `has_bracket<T>` be 1 for `T` = `Test`, `CTest` and `vector<int>`?

Comment: please do not remove the includes from the code. They are part of the code. It takes you time to remove them and everybody who wants to compile the code has to spend time to add them back again. Just leave them in

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry, I have added them in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats not how SFINAE works. `has_bracket<int>` does not explicitly specify second template argument, default is `void`, hence it is `has_bracket<int,void>`.

`decltype(T::operator[])` is never `void`. Hence, you always get the primary template. Moreover `decltype(T::operator[])` would require `operator[]` to be a static member.

SFINAE works when the specialisation has `void` as second argument for the "true" case, because thats the default of the primary template. `std::void_t` can be handy to have a type that is either `void` or a substitution failure:

```
template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct has_bracket
{
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct has_bracket<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::size_t{1}])> >
{
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};
```

[Complete Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4MGeTPz98)

If you are resitricted to < C++17, ie you cannot use `std::void_t` you can replace it with a handwritten (taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)):

> ```
> template< typename... Ts >
> struct make_void { typedef void type; };
>   
> template< typename... Ts >
> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
> ```

Summarizing from comments:

- The main issue with your code is that the second argument of the specialization is not `void`, hence it is never choosen.
- Your code uses `decltype(T::operator[])` and irrespective of the first bullet, this requires the operator to be static (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1KMTznq49))
- The issue with `decltype(&T::operator[])` is that you cannot take the address when there is more than one overload (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1fYM1eWj4))
- The previous solution in this answer uses `decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])` which requires that `operator[]` can be called with `0` as argument. That this "works" with `std::map<std::string,int>::operator[]` is an unfortunate coincidence, because a null pointer can be converted to `std::string`. It does not work when `operator[]` takes an argument that cannot be constructed from `0` (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3jPKMs6oK)).
- For this reason I changed the code above to `decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::size_t{1}])`. The literal `1` does not have the problem of implicit conversion to a null pointer. The solution now only detects `operator[]` that can be called with an integer.

Comment: Notice that this limits bracket which accepts `0`, so `std::map<std::string, T>` won't match.

Comment: OP might want `decltype(&T::operator[])`. But it fails with overload (const/not const mainly).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there any alternatives of `void_t` in C++14?

Comment: @Chun-YeLu see edit. In C++11 the obvious self-written `void_t` wont work due to a defect (see notes in the link in the answer), not sure if the same applies for C++14

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have test in C++14 and it works, thanks a lot! Another question is why `void_t<delctype(&T::operator[])>` can not work?

Comment: @Chun-YeLu it fails when there is more than one overload for `operator[]`

Comment: @Chun-YeLu do you need to detect `operator[]` with arguments other than `size_t` ? If not the code in the answer is fine. Otherwise, I'm not sure yet how to get it with c++14

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry but I still can not understand why it fails when there is more than overload for `operatoro[]`. In my case, `Test::operator[]` and `CTest::operator[]` has only one implement, but it still fails. The output of `cout << has_bracket<Test>::value` is 0.

Comment: And also `has_bracket<map<string, int>>::value` outputs `1` in my test. Here is the demo https://godbolt.org/z/eM9K944rr

Comment: @Jarod42 actually it would match `std::map<std::string, T>`, because `std::string` can be constructed from a null pointer :/. Simplest fix is to restrict to `operator[]`s that can be called with integer and use `1` which doesnt match a converions via some pointer type

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks a lot, very clearly explanation! BTW it seems that it is not available by using `void_t<decltype(declval<T>()[ARG])>` to detect `operator[]` with arguments other than `ARG`. If I want to detect for two or more types, for example allows both `size_t` and `string`, how can I achieve it?

Comment: @Chun-YeLu you could write a second specialization for types that have an `operator[](size_t  , std:.string)` for example. It gets hairy if you want to detect types that have both. Please clarify what you want exactly. Detect if the type has any `operator[]`? Or is it sufficient to check for  `operator[]` with specific signature?

Comment: @Chun-YeLu in your examples its only `operator[](size_t)` and thats fine for "array-like" types

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want to detect if the type has any `operator[]`. `void_t<decltype(declval<T>()[ARG])>` can only check one type at a time which is a little inconvenient. But `void_t<decltype(&T::operator[])>` can not work with overloading on the other hand. Seems like using `void_t<decltype<T>()[ARG]>` and create more specilizations is the best solution.

Comment: @chun-YeLu i suppose it would be simpler with c++20 concepts. Though, now I am curious, what do you need this information for? I mean suppose you know that a type has an `operator[]`, then to do anything with that `operator[]` you still need to know how to call it, ie just knowing it exists isnt that useful

Comment: @Chun-YeLu btw I think there must be a better way also in C++14. I just didnt try more to find it because I was waiting for you to clarify what you actually want to detect. I think it is possible to detect presence of `operator[]` irrespective of arguments.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number In my application I want to check if the type has implemented the `begin()` or `operator[]`, if implemented `begin()`, use iterator to copy the input data to an internal buffer. If implemented `operator[]`, use for-loop instead. But I found that I'm wrong, even though I can detect any kinds of `operator[]`, I still have to know how to call it. It's my fault.

Comment: @Chun-YeLu ok so I suppose this answer is fine for the question you did ask here. Maybe for your actual problem you can ask another one

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, your answer completly answered my question. Thanks for your kindly help.